# Laravel 4.1 Configuration for nginx on mavericks

Tags: nginx, laravel-4

I am trying to run Laravel4.1 on nginx. It's working fine on localhost:8080/ but when I got to localhost:8080/example I get 404 Not Found Error. This is my nginx configuration:

```
 http {

        server {
            listen       8080;
            server_name  localhost;

            #charset koi8-r;

            #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

            location / {
                root   /var/www/html/example/public;
                index  index.php;
            }

            #error_page  404              /404.html;

            # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
            #
            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                root   html;
            }

            # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
            #
            #location ~ \.php$ {
            #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
            #}

            # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
            #
            location ~ \.php$ {
                root           /var/www/html/example/public;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
            }

        }
}
```

This is my Laravel code:

```
Route::get('example', function()
{
    return View::make('example');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add rewriting, so any URL gets sent back to the front controller...

```
# Removes trailing slashes
if (!-d $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}

# Rewrite to index.php unless the request is for an existing file (image, js, css, etc.)
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    break;
}
```